# Why is it suggested to add a link to a video instead of embedding one for ADA compliance?

Tags: video, accessibility, video-embedding

I've seen on many suggestions lists for ADA compliance that videos be linked instead of embedded (like here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/creating-an-ada-compliant-website/). I read that this was from the Department of Human Service, on top of the DOJ recommendations, but no where can I find the reason why this is best practice for increased accessibility.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any of these resources? I've never heard that a link to a video is better than embedding. Also, looking at the HHS Section 508 Checklist, I see nothing about this mentioned -- https://www.hhs.gov/web/section-508/making-files-accessible/checklist/html/index.html

Comment: Put a link in the question @Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking to videos instead of embedding them was never a requirement in the W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 1.0 or 2.0. The [article you refer to](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/creating-an-ada-compliant-website/) dates from 2012, when embedded video players were typically based on Flash, and Flash often presented problems for keyboard users: in some browsers (e.g. Firefox), you could tab into the Flash animation/applet, but not out of it. Both [WCAG 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/#gl-own-interface) and WCAG 2.0 require that web content, including embedded content, should be keyboard accessible; WCAG 2.0 even explicitly mentions that there must be no [**keyboard trap**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#keyboard-operation-trapping).

If you provide a link to a video instead of embedding it, you avoid the keyboard trap issue that can be caused by Flash-based video players. Fortunately, there are many HTML5-based alternatives, including *accessible* video players, so that advice is somewhat dated now.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to the video gives the user the choice to choose his own video player (according to his own requirement and custom preferences).